# Java Printwriter Encoding UTF-8

Tags: java, netbeans, utf-8

```
File file2 = new File("output.txt");
    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file2, true);


    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fileWriter);
            out.println("üçı");
            out.close();
```

My code is here. I want to write to the file with encode UTF-8. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this please. this must work for you(i hope)

```
    OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file2), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outputStreamWriter);
    out.print("سلام");
```

maybe this will solve your problem.

Comment: File file2 = new File("output.txt");
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file2, true);

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fileWriter);
                out.println(new String(satir.getBytes("UTF-8"), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
                out.close();  I updated. Output is hatr�na
har�na

Comment: sorry i tested all of these codes before posting, so have no idea and will delete answer.

Comment: private static Charset utf8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");File file2 = new File("output.txt");
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file2, true);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fileWriter);
                out.println(new String(satir.getBytes(),utf8));
                out.close(); I wrote this code. But not working. I didnt understand error. Please help. :((